# Como fazer um loop no código python, unittest, selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Seguindo o código, como proceder em um loop para repetir sempre o mesmo preenchimento N vezes? Ou até mesmo pegando os nomes de uma lista .txt e populando em "nome"?

```
def teste(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("http://painelvix.com/galaxia4/formulario_testes.php?r=UUVJcFdZMXlZcE5XdVU2cGVEUjVMYllMNnVBYS9GajVVUkZ3em9tRDZObz0,")
    driver.find_element_by_name("nome").click()
    driver.find_element_by_name("nome").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_name("nome").send_keys("Teste de preenchimento")
    driver.find_element_by_name("email").click()
    driver.find_element_by_name("email").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("teste@teste.com.br")
    driver.find_element_by_name("perfil[]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*/text()[normalize-space(.)='Solicitar']/parent::*").click()
    self.assertEqual("Existe um teste pra este email cadastrado em: 28/03/2019", self.close_alert_and_get_its_text())
    driver.close()
```

Mais o unittest:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
unittest.main()
```

[Link com o arquivo .py](https://mega.nz/#!dhdAQaJR!i4rmMWaBAfgBtgIItsRdH8VkAAh7xFaaEq6N0JgdHo4)

Link do arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, acho que seu código tem muita informação não relacionada com o seu problema. Por isso, decidi fazer um exemplo mínimo replicável. Rode esse código no seu computador, veja como funciona e aplique ao seu programa:

```
from selenium import webdriver


lista_nomes = ['Joao Arruda Botelho','Camila Moraes Sarmento','Regina Moreira Salles']
lista_emails = ['joaoab@teste.com.br', 'camilamsb@teste.com.br', 'reginams@teste.com.br']

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for k in range(3):
    driver.get("http://painelvix.com/galaxia4/formulario_testes.php?r=UUVJcFdZMXlZcE5XdVU2cGVEUjVMYllMNnVBYS9GajVVUkZ3em9tRDZObz0,")
    driver.find_element_by_name("nome").click()
    driver.find_element_by_name("nome").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_name("nome").send_keys(lista_nomes[k])
    driver.find_element_by_name("email").click()
    driver.find_element_by_name("email").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys(lista_emails[k])
    driver.find_element_by_name("perfil[]").click()

driver.close()
```

Comment: Valeu pela dica. Mas quando roda o código, não funciona, abre somente a url, mas sem nenhuma ação. 
driver.find_element_by_name("nome".format(k)).send_keys(k)
Adicionando o código assim, vai o preenchimento, mas somente com o primeiro nome João. No caso o for não está funcionando.

Comment: Desculpa, eu esqueci de adicionar o `{}`. Vou editar

Comment: @HudsonSouza, tente novamente, por favor. Se não der certo, tente fazer um exemplo replicável, pq aí fica mais fácil de entender o que vc está tentando fazer.

Comment: Coloquei o link do arquivo. Basicamente é somente preencher um pequeno formulário, com isso, fazer um loop para preencher N vezes com nomes diferentes. Resumidamente, mais ainda: preenche envia, preenche envia... :)

Comment: @HudsonSouza Com seu código completo, ficou muito mais fácil. Veja minha nova solução

Comment: Obrigado, bem mais sucinto o código. Show!

Comment: Creio que pode colocar o `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` fora do loop, afinal já estará iniciado, não precisa reinstanciar toda vez

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento se fizer isso, gera um erro após o primeiro preenchimento. Rode no seu PC para ver

Comment: @Hartnäcking é porque esta usando driver.close sem necessidade também, bastaria por ele fora do loop também ... e claro independente de ajustar o código ou não um sleep pode ajudar notar os detalhes, claro que isso vai depender do que o AP vai fazer com o código.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é verdade. Vou editar o código para incluir essas melhorias

Comment: @Hartnäcking tem também uma tratativa pra se fazer, mas isso o AP nem mencionou, que é sobre os alerts que causam exception, mas só se ele formular uma nova pergunta que vc deverá responder ;) Bom fim de semana

Comment: PS: creio que seria algo +ou- assim conforme o código do AP: https://gist.github.com/brcontainer/89c286c237c0c710c0483ebface9c208 (para quem estiver curioso sobre as abreviações usadas no site: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6311/3635)